# Output PScustom object to CSV

Tags: powershell, pscustomobject, export-csv

A little background info;

i'm new to Powershell, but i do have some experience in VBA (excel mostly)

for a project i need to create a program to couple SQL result from a single column to input from users with a USB barcode scanner (just works like keyboard input + enter after each scan)

i run a SQL query which results the Instrument column from a table, this is stored in $values.instrument

Now i have a `read-host` for users to input a barcode that should match this instrument (scanned with usb barcode reader). and in case multiple times the same barcode is scanned, it's shown instrument (in the read-host) should be added to this barcode. So logically we do a `group-object` on the Barcode property. Now i can't directly export this so i made a `[pscustomobject]` to create a nice table. It shows correctly how i want in the shell, but `export-csv` is not working a i expect.

The code is as follows;

```
foreach($inst in $values.Instrument) #loop through every Instrument result from SQL

{
    
    $temp = New-Object System.Object
    $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Barcode" -Value (Read-Host -Prompt "scan de barcode van: $($inst)")
    $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "instrument" -Value $inst

    $instrument_data.Add($temp) | Out-Null
  
}


$groups = $instrument_data | Group-Object -property Barcode

 foreach ($instrument in $groups) {
        #$barcode = $instrument.Name
        #$instrument2 = ($instrument.Group.Instrument | Foreach-Object { "$_" }) -join ','
        [pscustomobject]@{'Barcode' = $instrument.Name; 'Instrument' = ($instrument.Group.Instrument | Foreach-Object { "$_" }) -join ','}
    } 
 


 $groups | export-csv -Path "export-path\file.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

this results in the follwing on the terminal as i expect;

[Terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNdVS.png)
I tried the normal `export-csv` as that should normally do the export like how the results are shown in terminal, but for some reason i see the system.object stuff instead of the format as shown in the terminal from the resulting `[pscustomobject]` :

[csv output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H6le.png)

Comment: I think you want to do this: `foreach ($instrument in $groups) { ... } | export-csv -Path "export-path\file.csv" -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: The pscustomobject is due to the object not being cast to the real type.  I like using Format-Table to help debug these issues.  So try $groups | Format-Table.

Comment: You're looping over `$groups`  in the last part creating the right output for CSV but all is going to the console as output never getting exported as CSV

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon should i put the CSV export inside the foreach block the next time?

Comment: No not inside, the problem with `foreach` loop is that you can pipe `Export-Csv` after it, might be easier done with a `ForEach-Object` otherwise using what you already have, the output from your loop should be captured: `$result = foreach ($instrument in $groups) {..` then exported `$result | Export-Csv ...`

Comment: aah thanks for your explanation. I understand it now. Powershell is realy different way of thinking compared to VBA what i'm used to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution, some of your answers pushed me in the right direction;

```
foreach($inst in $values.Instrument) #loop through every Instrument result from SQL

{
    
    $temp = New-Object System.Object
    $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Barcode" -Value (Read-Host -Prompt "scan de barcode van: $($inst)")
    $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "instrument" -Value $inst

    $instrument_data.Add($temp) | Out-Null
  
}


$groups = $instrument_data | Group-Object -property Barcode

    $groups | select Name, 
    @{Name=’instrument’;Expression={[string]::join(“,”, ($_.Group.Instrument))}} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | Out-File $outfile -Force -Encoding ascii
```

also changed the path of csv export to a variable for easier change in the future to $outfile

but this gives the solution i want, then only a header removal when the file is done and our software package can read the CSV :).

thank you all for the fast responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($group in $groups)
{
  $group | Format-Table
  table.Add($group) 
}
$table | Format-Table
```